# My impulse response does not tend to zero

Tags: impulse-response, transform, ifft, fourier, inverse

I am doing an IFFT of frequency response data achieved with Simulation tools.

When I plot my impulse response it looks wrong as the response does not tend to zero as it should. Instead there seems to be a rise in pressure towards the end of the signal.

My script looks like this:

```
close all;
clear all;
A = load('PvaluesAtReceiver.txt');
f = A(:,1);
Preal = A(:,2);
Pimag = A(:,3);
Prealpad = cat(1,Preal,zeros(48000-180,1));
Pimagpad = cat(1,Pimag,zeros(48000-180,1));
fpad = cat(1,f,zeros(48000-180,1));
enter preformatted text here
j = sqrt(-1);

Prealf = Prealpad(88:177);
Pimagf = Pimagpad(88:177);
ff = fpad(88:177);
Prealfpad = cat(1,Prealf,zeros(48000-90,1));
Pimagfpad = cat(1,Pimagf,zeros(48000-90,1));
ffpad = cat(1,ff,zeros(48000-90,1));
X_ff = Prealfpad + j*Pimagfpad;
X_ff = [zeros(ff(1),1); X_ff];
IRf = ifftshift(X_ff);
x_tf = ifft(IRf);
figure,plot(real(x_tf)), title('Impulse response filtered');
```

This produced the following plot:

[image]

Does anyone know why this doesn't tend to zero??

---

[image]

This is the frequency domain i want to transform.

Comment: Please plot also the magnitude frequency response.

Comment: Looks like your data is very noisy. You also do a lot of padding/resizing etc. which is hard to follow. Please add some comments to your code.

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for your reply. I have posted the updated commented script below as an asnwer.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo
The frequency response, with Magnitude on the y-axis and frequency on the x-axis is posted below also

Answer (score 1):

Note that the DFT transforms a *periodic* sequence into a *periodic* sequence. Hence, the result of your IFFT is intrinsically periodic and you should view it as such. The parts you are seeing at the end of it are thus just as well *behind* the start as they are *before* it.

Hence, this part may as well be some form of pre-ringing, stemming from a nonzero group delay of your filter.

Note also that the FFT implicitly periodifies your spectrum. It looks a little cut, so you may be missing some essential parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
close all;
clear all;
A = load('PvaluesAtReceiver.txt');

f = A(:,1); %frequencies of data
Preal = A(:,2); %Real part of data
Pimag = A(:,3); %Imaginary part of data

j = sqrt(-1); 

Prealf = Preal(88:177); %Filter data for the 125Hz band
Pimagf = Pimag(88:177); %Filter data for the 125Hz band
ff = f(88:177); %Filter data for the 125Hz band

Prealfpad = cat(1,Prealf,zeros(48000-90,1)); %Add zeros to increase time resolution
Pimagfpad = cat(1,Pimagf,zeros(48000-90,1)); %Add zeros to increase time resolution
ffpad = cat(1,ff,zeros(48000-90,1)); %Add zeros to increase time resolution

X_ff = Prealfpad + j*Pimagfpad;

IRf = ifftshift(X_ff); % Rearranges zero-frequency-shifted Fourier transform back to the original transform output

x_tf = ifft(IRf); %Inverse discrete Fourier transform
figure,plot(real(x_tf)), title('Impulse response filtered'); %Plot
```

This is the updated commented script.

Comment: I suggest starting slow by making sure each part of your script does what you want it to:
1) Start by simply taking the IFFT of the coefficients (Real + 1j*Imag).  That should give you a direct representation in the time domain of what you are looking at.  
2) Make sure your 125 Hz filtering works before applying it to a huge 48000 length signal.